# Split string into different column with sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How can I split this particular string in the column to three different column

**sample:**

```
Column_A
----------
{"nationalCode":"1234567893","username":"123","ip":"::1"}
{"nationalCode":"1234567892","username":"test","ip":"172.30.10.11"}
{"nationalCode":"1234567890"}
{"nationalCode":"1234567891","username":"test"}
```

should be

```
nationalcode|username|Ip
---------------------------
1234567893  |123     |::1 
1234567892  |test    |172.30.10.11
1234567890  |null    |null
1234567891  |test    |null
```

what I have tried so far for just one of the field is(I have no Idea how to solve it)

```
 select  SUBSTRING(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(ActionInput,CHARINDEX('nationalCode',ActionInput)+len('nationalCode":"'),CHARINDEX(',',ActionInput)),'""',''),0,11) as national1,
         REPLACE(SUBSTRING(ActionInput,CHARINDEX('username',ActionInput)+len('username":"'),CHARINDEX(',',ActionInput)),'"}','') as a

        from LogTBL
```

Comment: which sql server version?

Comment: @McNets sql-server-2008

Comment: Is it always a maximum of those three values and do they ALWAYS come in exactly the same order? Ideally you should never store data like this. This is even worse than xml and violates 1NF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you could use `Replace` to change `Column_A` into `XML` and get expected data by [VALUE()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/value-method-xml-data-type)

```
DECLARE @SampleData AS TABLE
(
    Column_A varchar(max)
)

INSERT INTO @SampleData
VALUES 
('{"nationalCode":"1234567893","username":"123","ip":"::1"}'),
('{"nationalCode":"1234567892","username":"test","ip":"172.30.10.11"}'),
('{"nationalCode":"1234567890"}'),
('{"nationalCode":"1234567891","username":"test"}')

;WITH temp AS
(
    SELECT CAST(REPLACE(replace(replace(replace(sd.Column_A, '":"', '="'),
                    '{"', '<x '),'}','></x>' ), '","','" ') AS xml) AS XmlValue
    FROM @SampleData sd
)
SELECT  t.XmlValue.value('(/x/@nationalCode)[1]', 'varchar(30)') AS nationalCode,
        t.XmlValue.value('(/x/@username)[1]', 'varchar(30)') AS username,
        t.XmlValue.value('(/x/@ip)[1]', 'varchar(30)') AS ip
FROM temp t
```

Demo link: http://rextester.com/YEPUI94059